# How can I set infinity focus on Androidk NDK

Tags: android, c++, camera, android-ndk, focus

I'm currently working about to develop a camera application with android ndk c++. I'm working on Samsung devices and I need totally infinity focus with good resolution. I tried some solutions but they're not good for me.

I wanna set correct, absolute and fix solution and it has to work stable every time, every situation.

Can you help me?

First one is **ACAMERA_CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF** with **ACAMERA_LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE - 0.0f** but resolution is so bad on one of my Samsung tablet(Galaxy Tab Active 4 Pro).

Second one is **ACAMERA_CONTROL_AF_EDOF_FOCUS**. This solution good but when I start the app and if I put my hands front of the camera, resolution looks so bad.

Third one is **ACAMERA_CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER**. When I start the application then it is trying to focus and if I got a good resolution and focus then I set **ACAMERA_CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED**. This is also good but not a good solution.